# Target vs Control in Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

In Marketing Cloud’s Journey Builder - Is there an option to split the entry source data extension in journey, with target and control group of about 10:90?

Comment: Welcome to salesforce.stackexchange.com!  This question is pretty unclear and could use a bit more detail.  You would get better answers with a better question.  What is the problem you are trying to solve?  What have you already tried to do? What does DE stand for?

Comment: Sorry that I wasnt clear enough, all I wanted to do was to split the source DE with control/ target to send email with in journey rather then having control removed outside journey and pushing target DE, reason was to capture those control records as part of the journey, with no message sent, only thing I need to figure out is how do we do reporting on them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very straightforward in a single journey, utilising the Random Split:

[image: Random Split screenshot]

This allows you to route your audience according to the percentage on the individual paths.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_split_journey_contacts_at_random.htm&type=5

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to mark the answer as accepted.